# Using a script to Organize a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

So I have a two flat files that is in the format as follows:

File1.txt

```
Customer1 12345 12346 12347
Customer2 14444 14445
```

File2.txt

```
12345 aol.com
12347 gmail.com
12346 google.com
14444 yahoo.com
14445 outlook.com
```

I need to be able to translate the file into something like this:

```
Customer1 aol.com google.com gmail.com
Customer2 yahoo.com outlook.com
```

This is what I have so far

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} $2 in a {print $0, a[$2]}' OFS='\t' File2.txt File1.txt
```

However this only looks at Column 2 of the first file, how can I expand it to look at all columns in file1

Comment: Do you use the three "." lines to separate the data?

Comment: @A.Villegas the three "." is just a representation of more data being there that follows the same pattern as lines above

Comment: `...What is the best way of going about this?` - i would choose a programming language which makes text processing easy, i.e. awk, Ruby or Perl.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can loop through fields. Try something like this -

```
$: awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next;}
        { printf "%s ", $1; 
          for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "%s ", a[$i]; 
          };
          printf "\n";
        }' File2.txt File1.txt
Customer1 aol.com google.com gmail.com
Customer2 yahoo.com outlook.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let awk go through the file, separate `NF==2` and `NF==3` records into two hashtables/arrays, then link the two arrays and print output.

You can also go through the file twice to do the same logic.

I think this gives you a good start.

Comment: What would something look like? Sorry I am new to scripting

Comment: asking for working codes at SO is not welcomed. @Keith

Comment: Was able to break it down a little more so that I now have two different files, make it easier to use awk. Was able to come up with the following "$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} $2 in a {print $0, a[$2]}' OFS='\t' File2.txt File1.txt" but it only searches column 2 of file 1, do you know how i can expand it to apply it to all columns in file 1?